# React Konva: onMouseOver doesn't trigger when a shape above it is removed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-konva, konva

I have a project with two `<Rect/>` on top of each other.
The `<Rect/>` at the bottom changes its color when the cursor is hovering over it.

```
export const BottomSquare = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("green");
  return (
    <Rect
      width={100}
      height={100}
      opacity={1}
      fill={color}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        setColor("blue");
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setColor("green");
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

the `<Rect/>` at the top changes its position to be away from the bottom `<Rect/>` when it's clicked. This `<Rect/>` is smaller than the bottom one.

```
export const TopSquare = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  return (
    <Rect
      {...position}
      width={50}
      height={50}
      opacity={1}
      fill="grey"
      onClick={(event) => {
        setPosition({ x: 100, y: 100 });
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Hovering over the top `<Rect/>` does not trigger the color changing logic of the bottom `<Rect/>`, which is the expected behavior.

However, when clicking on the top `<Rect/>`, and it's moved away, making the cursor to hovering over the bottom `<Rect/>`, the `onMouseOver()` logic doesn't trigger unless I move the cursor for at least 1 pixel. This feels like a `onMouseMove()` behavior rather than `onMouseOver()`.

[image: react-konva onMouseOver issue]

What I want is for the bottom `<Rect/>` to be able to trigger the `onMouseOver()` logic when the top one is removed.

I tried `onMouseEnter()` and `onMouseMove()`, but the issue is still there.

How can I solve this issue?

[reproduced example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-julien-pb2zt6?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. get the reference to the bottom `rect` by applying some *id* to it and then programatically start the `mouseover` event when user clicks on the top `rect`.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hugle-bzj4jx

```
export const TopSquare = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  return (
    <Rect
      {...position}
      width={50}
      height={50}
      opacity={1}
      fill="grey"
      onClick={(event) => {
        const stage = event.target.getStage();
        const node = stage?.findOne('#bottomRect');
        node?.fire('mouseover');
        setPosition({ x: 100, y: 100 });
      }}
    />
  );
};

export const BottomSquare = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("green");
  return (
    <Rect
      width={100}
      height={100}
      id="bottomRect"
      opacity={1}
      fill={color}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        setColor("blue");
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setColor("green");
      }}
    />
  );
};
```